# Unexpected token error when trying to run server

Tags: node.js, npm, openssl, private-key, npx

I am trying to run a server using openSSL command. I generated a private key which successfully created in a key.pem file and a certificate successfully created in a cert.pem file. When i run the command `npx serve --ssl-cert cert.pem  --ssl-key key.pem` it starts running but then I get an error saying "unexpected token error" and nothing else happens. Could this be a security blocker or are there any possible workarounds?

node version: 8.11.3
openSSL version: 3.3.6

[image]

I reinstalled Node, recreated a new folder and restarted the process, checked the versions were up to date. Still didn't notice a difference. Any ideas?